# Не удается выбрать записи из таблицы SQLite базу

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, sqlite, entity-framework

Доброго времени суток!
Второй день не могу понять почему EF не вытаскивает значения из таблицы...

Скрипт создания таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE "Category" ( `Id` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
                          `Name` TEXT NOT NULL, 
                          `MinPercent` REAL NOT NULL, 
                          `MaxPercent` REAL NOT NULL, 
                          `HasEmployee` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
                          `Surcharge` REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
                          `SalaryRate` REAL NOT NULL, 
                          `CurrencyId` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
                          PRIMARY KEY(`Id`), 
                          FOREIGN KEY(`CurrencyId`) REFERENCES `Currency`(`Id`) )
```

Код класса модели:

```
[Table("Category")]
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Single MinPercent { get; set; }
    public Single MaxPercent { get; set; }
    public Boolean HasEmployee { get; set; }
    public Single Surcharge { get; set; }
    public Single SalaryRate { get; set; }
    public Int32 CurrencyId { get; set; }
}
```

Код DB контекста:

```
public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
```

Выбираю данные так:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories
    {
        get
        {
            return _dbContext.Category;
        }
    }
```

И всё это выбирает 0 записей, хотя в таблице записи присутствуют. Кто сталкивался или у кого есть идеи как это побороть, подскажите! Спасибо!

Comment: Покажите как вы запрашиваете записи из БД. Это основное, а не скрипт создания БД. И EF у вас 6-й или Core?

Comment: public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories
        {
            get
            {
                return _dbContext.Category;
            }
        }

Comment: `return _dbContext.Category` ничего не вернет, нужно сделать запрос с помощью LINQ.

Comment: @Bulson, а почему другие возвращают?

Comment: Во-первых, никто к свойствам напрямую запросы не подключает. Во-вторых, почитайте прежде [уроки](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/2.1.php)